# Error while generating cookbook: Missing shared library "libcrypt.so.1"

Tags: linux, shared-library, chef

I encountered an error when trying to generate a cookbook using the command `chef generate cookbook test-cookbook`. The error message I received is as follows:

```
ERROR : exit status 127
/opt/chef-workstation/embedded/bin/ruby:  error while loading shared libraries: libcrypt.so.1: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

The error appears to be caused by a missing shared library called `libcrypt.so.1`.

How can I fix this issue and generate the cookbook successfully?

Answer (score 0):

It's telling you that you need to install `libcrypt.so`.

You can check with `ldd $(type -p chef)` which lists the shared libraries needed by `chef`. Since `chef` makes use of functions in `libcrypt.so`, and you don't have it installed, `chef` can't work.

On Ubuntu, one would find the package to install (to obtain `libcrypt.so`) with:

```
dpkg -S libcrypt.so
```

but you didn't let us know which distribution you're using.

Comment: i already installed chef and also update the packages with yum update -y . Also checked chef version it is showing all the output correct but after entering above command to create cookbook error is showing

Answer (score 0):

I was having the same problem, Installing `libxcrypt-compat` seemed to fix my problem.

```
sudo pacman -Syu libxcrypt-compat
```

Answer (score 0):

This is how i resolved it.

If you face this error while running command

```
# chef generate cookbook my_cookbook
```

> exit status 127 /opt/chef-workstation/embedded/bin/ruby: error while
> loading shared libraries: libcrypt.so.1: cannot open shared object
> file: No such file or directory

this means your `libcrypt.so.1` is probably missing. You can install all pacakges in Linux/AWS/Redhat by,

```
sudo yum update
sudo yum install glibc
```

Now search for library

```
find / -name "libcrypt.so.1" 2>/dev/null
```

If the find command shows nothing, this means "*libcrypt.so.1*" is still missing. Download and install it manually by,

```
yum provides "*/libcrypt.so.1"
yum install "*/libcrypt.so.1"
```

Now search again, it would show paths to the library.

```
find / -name "libcrypt.so.1" 2>/dev/null
```

Run the `chef generate` command now, it would be working most probably.

```
# chef generate cookbook my_cookbook
```